# Best way to improve JSPlumb performance when redrawing 200+ connections

Tags: javascript, raphael, jsplumb

Currently I am using [JSPlumb](http://www.jsplumb.org/doc/home.html) for drawing connections between elements.  However JSPlumb is taking an excessively long time to redraw connections in graphs of 200 or more.

I was contemplating exploring [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) to see if performance improvements could be gained.  Can anyone suggest improvements that can be made to increase the performance of JSPlumb?

Related question, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29961454/jsplumb-detach-multiple-connection-slowed-down

Comment: Added linking and expanded the search to include performance improvements to JSPlumb beyond just switching frameworks.  You will also want to include some code samples. Vast differences in performance will exist between vanilla verse jquery, as well as approach taken for the redraw.  Code samples **always** help!